# Which course would be better - architecture (or) games development??

Tags: game-industry

And will the job oppurtunities in games development field be good??  Which course can i prefer in these both??

Comment: No, and, whichever you like. What are you asking?

Comment: This is a poorly defined, subjective question, and it's very specific to your needs. Ask in chat if you can't make this more concrete and meaningful for a general audience.

Comment: This is a "Gorilla vs. Shark" question, one of the classic types of questions that don't work well in this format.  Explanations and examples (and advice for fixing such questions) here:  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/

Answer (score 8):

As others have said, this question isn't entirely meaningful as it stands, however this type of question I've heard many times over the years, so a meaningful answer may still be beneficial to future readers.

The gaming industry is extremely broad, and even moreso recently with the huge growth of game-capable smartphones.

For **web-browser games**:

- Flash/Actionscript (won't work on iPhones, iPads, and a few other devices)
- Unity 3 (won't work on Linux), uses C# (a sub-set of it at least), JavaScript
- HTML5 and WebGL are becoming bigger on the scene. If you learn these now and they become widely used down the road you could find yourself in a good position. Signs are currently pointing to these growing quickly in the next 5 years.

For **mobile phone games**:
 - Unity 3 (Android, iOS)
 - Objective C (iOS)

For Windows PC games (that aren't web), if you're looking for job opportunities, most of the industry still uses C++. A lot of 3rd Party middleware and Game Engines are written in C++ as well, so if you want to work for one of those companies or work for a company that uses that software, C++ is a good bet. Also DirectX is fairly standard, but some companies use game engines that support OpenGL, which is important if the game is going to be multiplatform.

For **multiplatform PC games**:
 - Java (runs on Windows, Mac, Linux)
 - Some companies will contract other companies to write wrappers for their game so it can run on other Mac/Linux.

For **OSX games**:
 - Java
 - C
 - Objective C
 - OpenGL

I would focus on a part of the gaming field that most interests you, and start researching the pay for particular positions that you could be applying for in the future. Average starting salary in the gaming industry for a programmer is around $50k/year, rising to around $90k/year after 5 years, and can get up to $120k-150k/year for leads and directors. Bear in mind however that the industry tends to be clumped in certain geographical areas. In the US about half of the companies are on the west coast, where cost of living can be very expensive, so a high salary can be somewhat offset.

Also, consider that not all game programmers are programming for the game itself. Many programmers are doing things like writing tools for designers, or writing scripts for automated builds, or creating web interfaces for linking tools, game, and database together. The list goes on. This kind of programming covers many languages, like SQL, Python, PHP, HTML, etc...